# Laravel 5 model validation and authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am facing a dilemma on how to implement validation in my laravel project, let me explain the situation.

1. I am using an angular JS front end user interface and communicating to laravel using [restful resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).
2. I am using [form request validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation) in my controller's `store()` and `update()` methods to validate the data via the `rules()` method and determining the authorization using `authorize()` method, which ensures both that my data is correct, and only users with correct permission levels can add/edit data. Everything is working well at this point, so long as the data is coming via a form/ajax request made to the api.

Now, here is the problem. Sometimes the insert/edit operation needs to be done programatically, for e.g. whenever a row is created in table A, a row needs to be created in table B, but before doing so, it should also run the same validation rules and check authorization that it would do if table B was created using a form request, but if I just called say `TableA::Create([])` the row would be created without any validation.

Sure, I can use `Validator::make()` inside the model as well but then,
a) it makes the model cluttered b) is a repetition of code

So, my objective is to ensure that no matter how Table A's records are going into the database, if its done from the application, the checks will be performed before saving the data, while keeping the validation and authorization rules central. It seems to me that the way to go is to put a hook onto the model's "saving" event and somehow trigger the formrequest validator? But I am not sure.

I saw Jeffrey Way's [automatic model validator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation), but that is for Laravel 4. Is there any elegant way to do this in Laravel 5.x ?

Also, as an add-on question, when I had asked this question elsewhere, a few people said they were "not a fan of model based validation", without explaining why it is not a good idea for them, so I would also like to know what are the drawbacks of model based validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend taking a step back. There is a temptation to try to abstract everything so not a single line of logic is ever repeated, but you need to understand why/what you are validating here.

At the early stages of developing an application, you may get the feeling that you are repeating validation logic **everywhere**, and possibly concerned you will miss something if you put the validation in a controller - for example, *"what happens if I add a controller method and fail to validate the data before updating the model?"*. So the natural step following this is to push the validation into the model.

**But!** You should go back to thinking about what you are validating. What you validate in your controller, **is not always the same** as what you validate in your model.

For more information about MVC validation, see the following link on Stacks sister site:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/in-mvc-should-a-model-handle-validation

In my opinion, the trap is that at the early stages of development, controller and model validation are *sooooo* similar you may think they are one and the same. This happens because you naturally start with some simple models to get the ball rolling. You just validated (in the controller) that the users first name is not "*_-_kablamo!-_-*", then in the model you are doing the same thing.

When you move past your simple user model, you will come to find that your models and controllers are more complex and validation dependent on possibly more than just the current request data - for example it could be dependent on other data in the system, the time of the year, the seasons, if the moons are aligned.

**I hear you scream** well that doesn't really help with the first paragraph where you said "what happens if I miss validation in some new controller method?". My answer to that is simple, testing. Your unit tests should be picking that up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

No.

And this is a serious issue that has had far too much conversation and not enough of a solution.

Laravel assumes you can validate at the front end, at the route, at the controller, or at the model, but the architecture of the code assumes that most users will validate closer to the user - either at the route, or at the controller - and not in the model.  This is ok for simple solutions.  It's not ok when models can be used by multiple controllers with different responsibilities.

Models need to serve as the single point of authority for rules and validation.
Controllers and Routes can apply ADDITIONAL validations that suit purposes.

From 40 years of doing this, the more functionality you have, the more developers you have, the more financial impact your data can have one someone who might sue you, the closer your validation will need be performed to the back end.  The smaller your application, the fewer the developers and the less important your information, the more your information will be validated near the front end.

However, in general you validate for different purposes at the route, model, controller and database.  (What someone said above.)

The 'testing will catch it' is a sort of millennial (in the pejorative) answer to the question. Either your business rules are declarative and observable or they are not declarative and 'magical'.  And Jared has a bit of a ... strange relationship with declarative and observable now and then.

There are a variety of packages that used to work well, but I am not sure are current.

**1. laravel-ardent/ardent**

**2. mortimer/poignant**

**3. jaspaul/eloquent-model-validation**

The 'simplest' answer is to create a base class that overrides the save function, performs the validation, and catches any errors, adding them to a bucket.

Personally I don't know why 'Ardent' isn't just 'the way it's done'.  Unfortunately the author doesn't seem to keep it going.